# На странице знаков ссылка на страницу про UTC ведёт на англоязычную wiki

Tags: дефект, предложение, локализация, справка

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно заменить на [нашу версию](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F).

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/300519/339911